# Vertical align any inline element in any div using margin-auto

Tags: css, html, margin, vertical-alignment

I am designing a text field which I want to be appear vertically-middle of a div. I want the black color div to be show vertically center of the blue (`id=srch`) div.

**HTML & CSS:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

* {
    vertical-align:baseline;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    border:0 none;
    outline:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;   
}
html {
    height:100%;
}

#outerwrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    border: solid thin #333;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#header {
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#999;
}
input {
    border:solid thin #ab1; 
}
#srch{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#00f;
}
#srch div{
    margin: auto 0 auto 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #000;
}
#contentWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color:#0F0
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="outerwrapper">
  <div id="header">Header

      <div id="srch">
        <div>
            <input type="tel" name="aa"/>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contentWrapper">
    Content Wrapper
  </div>  

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My approach:** I give the black div top and bottom margin auto but it is not working (also for the horizontal center [left and right `margin:auto`] it is working). Does `margin:auto` only work for left and right?

I want to know why this is happening, and I don't want any other solution like:

1. Display text inline with a vertical-align div.
2. Display with proper padding or margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin: auto` does not work for top and bottom. If `margin-top: auto` or `margin-bottom: auto` is specified, [their used value is 0](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height). Here's an [article about how you can achieve vertical centering](http://www.search-this.com/2008/05/15/easy-vertical-centering-with-css/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some jQuery here to calculate the height of parent container.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tQBVy/

Comment: In this case the parent container has a static height, and it's an easy matter of finding a good value for the margin. There's no need to make more complicated than necessary.

Comment: The article you have linked in your post is a static solution but with the fiddle I have given you can use the vAlign function to any element and make it vertically center. I guess the function makes it more easy. let me know your comment

Comment: Yes, but in the code that the OP posted there is also a static solution and no need to calculate the height dynamically. I can absolutely see the need of a dynamic solution for stuff like this, but not in this particular case. BTW, I like your solution!

Comment: Vote up would be better in this case then :-) Cheers!

Comment: +1 But I don't necessarily think it's a good solution in this case. :)